# how to use array combinationn on a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

If the values I was looking for were in two 1 dimensional arrays say, `a1 = [valueineed,valueidontneed,valueidontneed]` and `a2 = [valueineed,valueidontneed,valueidontneed]`, i could do

```
array1.combination(2).select { |x, y| array2.include? x + y }.each do |x,y|
 do_something x, y
end
```

but I have this array instead. `a1 = [[valuineed,valueidontneed],[valueineed,valueidontneed]], a2 = [[valueineed,valueidontneed],[valueineed, valueidontneed]]`
How do I acheive the same results the above program got on the previous array on the new array

Comment: Replace `array1` with `array1.flatten`, ditto for `array2`.

Comment: Maybe delete this question as well. Seems more of an extension of your previous question.

Comment: Im sorry, can i get any other method apart from flattening the array. Flattening the array will bring other variables to the options. can i get an array of [valueineed,valueineed,valueineed] from the multidimensional array.

Comment: With the example data you provided, you can do `map(&:first)` to get only the first values in each subarray.

Comment: Thank you very much